Where can i find a reference with explanation of each term about Poisson equation in anisotropic media?
I studied about Poisson equation on anisotropic media with equation as such
$$
k_{11}\dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} + (k_{12} + k_{21})\dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} + k_{22}\dfrac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} = g(x,y)
$$
On heat conduction, every each of its term means heat distribution towards each direction ($x$ and $y$) on my case. I come to this conclution from a research with my prof and friends on Dual Reciprocity Boundary Element Method (DRBEM) in anisotropic Poisson equation. Currently, i am seeking a book or journal etc with such explanation. I have read two books with title 'Partial Differential Equations' by Lawrence C. Evans and 'Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order' by David Gilberg and Neil S. Trudinger. However, i still cannot find (or understand) the explanation.

Think in terms of the physics. If $q$ is the heat flux density and $\theta$ is the temperature, one constitutive relation is $q := -k\nabla\theta$. Another is, with physical constraints on a matrix $K$, $q := -K\nabla\theta$.

Let $K = \begin{pmatrix} k_{11} & \frac{k_{12}+k_{21}}{2} \\ \frac{k_{12}+k_{21}}{2} & k_{22}\end{pmatrix}$. Now notice that your PDE reads $\nabla\cdot(K\nabla u) = g$. In this context, $K$ is often termed a diffusion tensor and it assumed to be positive definite. This diffusion operator corresponds to the energy functional given by the quadratic form $\int (\nabla u)^TK \nabla u~\mathrm{d}x$. Using the spectral theorem, we can see that $K$ has positive eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenvectors, called them $v_1$ and $v_2$. Now if $\nabla u = v_i$ at a point, then we have
$$
\nabla\cdot(K\nabla u) = \nabla\cdot(\lambda_i\nabla u) = \lambda_i\nabla^2u.
$$
From this, we can see that this operator acts similarly to the standard Laplacian except that it scales the directions that $u$ varies in depending on the eigenvectors of $K$. This is used a lot in image processing to construct diffusion tensors that diffuses in specific directions while keeping others stationary to preserve edges and other features. Image processing literature may be a fruitful direction and I have cited a common book in the field.
Aubert, Gilles; Kornprobst, Pierre, Mathematical problems in image processing. Partial differential equations and the calculus of variations. Foreword by Olivier Faugeras, Applied Mathematical Sciences 147. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 0-387-95326-4/hbk). xxv, 286 p. (2002). ZBL1109.35002.

Thank you very much for your answer. It helps me continue finishing my final project.
